# How to open first sheet and write to the second column using openpyxl?

Tags: openpyxl

I'm using an existing excel sheet and the Zillow API to pull the square feet from each house in my neighborhood.  I want to open an existing excel workbook, make the first worksheet active, and write the square feet in the second column.

I think the problem is it's not make the worksheet active to write the square feet into the second column.  There's quite a bit of code underneath that works when I print to console.  I'm trying to use a simple ws.write method but it doesn't recognize ws as a class.

```py
def neighborhood_test():
    location = "Address List Cypress Bend.xlsx"
    wb_out = Workbook(location)
    ws = wb_out.active
    print(type(ws))
```

It should return a worksheet class but returns class 'NoneType' instead.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong but now I need to learn how to iterate through it using other xlrd and Zillow API methods.  This is the code you need to use an existing excel sheet.

```py
def neighborhood_test():
    location = "Address List Cypress Bend.xlsx"
    wb_out = load_workbook(location)
    worksheet = wb_out.active
    print(worksheet.title)
```

This successfully prints out the first sheet which is Sheet1 for me.